# Update FK from PK using PHP-MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, insert, foreign-keys

i'm new in php and mysql
i have a problem
i have 2 tables

```
<?php
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO request (date, type_request, subject, customer)
    VALUES (NOW(), '".$type."', '".$subject."', '".$username."')");

    $fk = mysql_query("insert into feedback (id_request) select id_request from request where id_request = last_insert_id ");

?>
```

i've been doing that but still cannot fill the id_request in table feedback
the structure of table is like this

Table Request

```
id_request auto_increment not_null,-->PK
date,
type_request,
subject,
customer
```

Table Feedback

```
id_feedback auto_increment not_null,
id_request,---FK
feedback_user
```

can anyone give suggest how to update the foreign key

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code

```
$fk = mysql_query("insert into feedback (id_request) select id_request from request where id_request = last_insert_id ");
```

replace `last_insert_id` with `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

since its a MySQL function and not a field.

Comment: @why_u Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: sorry i just read it.thanks, and i've check this answer,,thanks for the information

Answer (score 1):

I know I will get flamed for this, but this is how I would do it:

```
<?php
$date       = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$req_query  = 'INSERT INTO request (date, type_request, subject, customer) '.
              "VALUES ('$date', '$type', '$subject', '$username')";
$req_result = mysql_query($req_query);

$fk_query   = 'SELECT MAX(id) id FROM request '.
              "WHERE date = '$date' AND type_request = '$type' ".
              "AND subject = '$subject' AND customer = '$username'";
$fk_result  = mysql_query($fk_query);
$fk_row     = mysql_fetch_assoc($fk_result);
$fk         = $fk_row['id'];

$fb_result  = mysql_query("INSERT INTO feedback (id_request) VALUES($fk)");
?>
```

Comment: This would be the right way to do it. This takes care of the fact that anything that happens in between those two queries is taken care of.

Comment: okay i'll try it soon it works or not.thanks for the help, and i would ask, that my way to type the code is true or correct?sorry if my english was bad, and my code bad too, i'm a junior programmer